# printf -v is an illegal option, in Bitbucket pipeline. And a question about <<

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, deployment

Hello I'm brand new to shell scripting, so sorry if this is trivial.
How do you use `printf` command with the `-v` option?

In our `deployment.sh` file we have this line
`printf -v BITBUCKET_COMMIT_str %q "$BITBUCKET_COMMIT"`

```
echo 'Initializing new deployment'
printf -v BITBUCKET_COMMIT_str %q "$BITBUCKET_COMMIT"
echo "commit string $BITBUCKET_COMMIT_str"
```

When the Bitbucket pipeline runs, it always fails at this line. With the error `printf -v is an illegal option`.

Error from Bitbucket

```
Initializing new deployment
commit string 
deployment.sh: 28: printf: Illegal option -v
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! XXXXX deploy: `sh deployment.sh`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the XXXX deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/XXX-debug.log
```

I've tested the `printf -v` command in a local terminal and it works fine, so I don't know why it doesn't work in the Bitbucket build pipeline. I've tried replacing `printf` with just a variable, but then I get a syntax error later on in the file. I think that's because we try to use the variable as in input for another command

```
"bash -s $BITBUCKET_COMMIT_str" <<\HERE
     echo "TEST MADE IT HERE"
     BUILD_FOLDER="BUILD_$BITBUCKET_COMMIT"
     echo "Build: $BUILD_FOLDER"
    ...
    HERE
```

On another note I'm not entirely sure what the above script is trying to do. I haven't been able to find what the `bash -s` command does. I think this command is trying to append a file with the contents of the `HERE` block. The script inside the `HERE` block doesn't seem to run unless I change `<<` to `>>` The code inside the `HERE` block seems to run. But from what I understand about the `<<` that change doesn't really make sense.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Most of my team is on holiday so I'm having a tough time with this. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `printf -v` in general does not work - except for `ksh93` ans `bash`. Do yu use bash?

Comment: @adam.k, so what's the error message you get, exactly? What's the line that uses `printf -v`, exactly? Is there really that dash in front of `-printf -v` like you show? How do you run the script? Also, what's that `printf -f` command you refer to?

Comment: @ilkkachu `printf -f` and `-printf -v` were typos. I've fixed them in my question. The exact line that uses `printf -v` is what I posted. That is the only command on that line. The script runs when I push the code up to Bitbucket (I'm not sure how to do it locally, because the script uses Bitbucket variables).

Comment: @schily The top of the script file is  `#!/bin/sh` I've tried changing to `#!/bin/bash`, and I get the same . I'm not sure what we are actually using. I don't seem to have the access rights to look at deploy settings on Bitbucket :(

Comment: Do you have `#! /bin/bash` at the top of your deployment script? How exactly does your BitBucket config run the deployment script?

Comment: the `-v` option is a bash4+ feature iirc, which version of bash do you hve?

Comment: @roaima The script runs in Bitbucket, meaning that it is executed. However, the script does not run successfully. The script throws an error, and fails the build process.

Comment: Sorry, thank you. Yes I did miss that.

Comment: @Jetchisel, no, `printf -v` is in Bash 3.2 too. Also, Bash's error message is different. (which is one reason I asked for the exact error message -- it helps identify the shell that actually runs)

Comment: @schily, my copy of ksh93 doesn't even support that :/ Zsh does, though.

Comment: How exactly does your BitBucket config run the script? If it's doing `sh deployment.sh`, all the shebangs in the world won't help.

Comment: @ilkkachu, yeah my bad twas the printing of time/date i was thinking about using the `-v`

Comment: @ilkkachu You are right, I was mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
printf -v BITBUCKET_COMMIT_str %q "$BITBUCKET_COMMIT"
echo "commit string $BITBUCKET_COMMIT_str"

deployment.sh: 28: printf: Illegal option -v
```

That looks like an error message from Dash, Debian's `/bin/sh`. This is the point where the question would be if the hashbang at the start of the script is correct, but you already mentioned that in the comments.

The workaround for `-v` would be using command substitution, `var=$(printf whatever)` but then you'd hit a problem with `%q`, since Dash doesn't support that either, and it's somewhat difficult to replace since the `${var/pattern/replacement}` expansion is also not supported.

But look at the next line. You're using that variable `BITBUCKET_COMMIT_str` to print to the user. That doesn't necessarily require quoting valid for shell input, which is what `%q` does. (And `%q` doesn't even produce nice-looking output, it prioritizes using backslashes instead of just using single quotes.) So, if that's the only place you use the variable, and it doesn't contain e.g. newlines (if it's a commit id or such, it probably doesn't), you could probably just skip the `printf` altogether, and use something like this:

```
echo "commit string '$BITBUCKET_COMMIT'"
```

If you **really** need Bash's `%q`, and Bash is at all available, an obvious but very overkill solution is to call Bash to do it:

```
quotedvar=$(bash -c 'printf %q "$1"' bash "$var")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. $BITBUCKET_COMMIT_str is used lower down in the file as well. The echo was there for my testing to see if something is actually being printed. I'll try the overkill option in that case.

Comment: @adam.k, still, if it's not really used as input to shell as code (through `eval` or a manually started shell), you probably don't need the quoting. If it's just used a variable in the arguments of some cmd, then just `somecmd blah blah "$BITBUCKET_COMMIT"` should do

Comment: OK thanks for your help. Overkill option works, as does just using a normal variable, at least for getting rid of the error. There is still a syntax issue somewhere else in the file, so I'll have to do more digging around that.